# GNU sed matching lines with unescaped characters

Tags: regex, linux, sed, terminal, gnu

I'm running into an issue with SED and it's not quite behaving the way I'd expect it. I'm attempting to append to lines (using lines breaks, \n) after a match. I'm attempting to auto-fix a Service file for all our deployed machines, and all future ones (well, until the vendor fixes it).

Suppose I have a file called "foo.service" which looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo
After=network.target

[Service]
User=UserFoo
Environment="SERVICENAME=foo"
Environment="SERVICEPATH=/opt/foo"
Environment="SERVICEMAINCLASS=com.GoogleFoo.service.foo.ServiceRunner
```

I need to match sed to "[Service]". I cannot match to "Service" otherwise it will write the output multiple times (**it'll match to the line: [Service] and the line "Environment="SERVICEMAINCLASS=com.GoogleFoo.service.foo.ServiceRunner**"". I built a much simpler file to work on expressions to see where it's going wrong, the  best I can find are the brackets are an unescaped character.

I've tried two commands which give different results. (Results -> [Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDVLw.jpg))

```
sed -i "/[abc]/aRestart=on-failure\nRestartSec=60" TestFile && cat TestFile
sed -i "/abc/aRestart=on-failure\nRestartSec=60" TestFile.bak && cat TestFile.bak
```

Where testFile and TestFile.bak are the same file

```
[abc]
cde
efg
ghi
```

Where am I going wrong with the commands? I've tried encasing the patterns in various quotes and other escape characters, but it's not worked to date. Any input?

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu)-[sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/^\[Service\]/&\nRestart=on-failure\nRestartSec=60/' foo.service
```

### Output

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo
After=network.target

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
User=UserFoo
[...]
```

### Explanations

- you need to escape square brackets, because `sed` treat these as a *class* of characters
- `&` is what matched in the substitution

Comment: I have no idea how to mark this as the answer, but thank you!

I'm guessing part of the reason why my commands failed to work even after attempting to escape the characters is because I wasn't using Extended Regex (-E).

interesting that you're using & instead of a. My understanding was that 'a' should append after a match. But after trying your command with it substituted, it re-wrote the [Service] line with 'a'.

Edit: Marked as accepted!

Comment: Removed not needed `-E` switch